# Kibana : How to dissociate a visualization from timepicker

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I have a Kibana dashboard with some visualizations and each visualization changes when i change the time window. Is there a way to display a visualization that does not change and stays fixed? For example, i want to display the total number of records present in my index. Now i have this in a nice dashboard. I only want this number to change if the actual number of records changes. Otherwise, I want it fixed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a second index pattern for that. It is a kinda hackish solution but it works.

1. Create a new index pattern. Configure it just like your regular one, but uncheck "contains time-based events". This way you will get an index pattern where the time picker doesn't apply.
2. Create your visualization from this second index pattern.
3. In case you want a certain fixed time range to apply: Add the time range as a normal filter in the query for this visualization.

Comment: Thanks Cherry! This should work, however, what will be the impact on storage? Wont i be storing duplicate data? It would be ideal if i could fuel the visualization based on an aggregation query.

Comment: As I understand it, if you have both index patterns point to the same actual index, then the only duplicate data will be the fields list in Kibana.

Comment: In Kibana 6.2 the error `An index pattern with the title '...' already exists.` appears if you try to create a second pattern for the same wildcard.  I'm able to create multiple index patterns for the same index with different time fields by shortening the pattern.  So I have "inventory-*" and "inventory*" and could have "inventor*" and so on.